# Add li to ul with looking for if exists

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

i'm adding thinks getting from a input field into a list. The adding function works well but i want to check if the string, which the user wants to add already exists. So i want something like that but don't know the right functions to use

HTML

```
First name:
<input type="text" id="firstname">
<br>
<p>Other people's names:</p>
<ul id="demo"></ul>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Submit' />
```

javascript

```
var list = document.getElementById('demo');

function changeText2() {
    var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    var listElement = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
    // here is the missing code
    if (listElement.text is not in list){
        var entry = document.createElement('li');
        entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstname));
        list.appendChild(entry);
    }
    else alert("is already in !");
}
```

EDIT*

The Code from above in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/be6ayfkp/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an array and push in it each name, you add for the first time. So each time you try to insert an new item, you will do a check in the array to see if this name has already been added. In terms of code:

```
var addedNames = [];
var list = document.getElementById('demo');

function changeText2() {
    var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;

    // Array object has a method called indexOf, with only one argument
    // the item we are looking for. If this item is not in the array, the 
    // method returns -1. Otherwise, the method returns it's position.
    // For instance, let that we have defined the following array. 
    // var numbers = [1,2,3,4].
    // Then numbers.indexOf(5) returns -1.
    // While numbers.indexOf(4) returns 3.
    if (addedNames.indexOf(firstname)==-1){
        var entry = document.createElement('li');
        entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstname));
        list.appendChild(entry);
        // We add the inserted name in the array for later checks.
        addedNames.push(firstname);
    }
    else alert("is already in !");
}
```

Please have a look [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ztvqjzo/)

Comment: well but it's not working. Try it. I've added it to my post. If i add linda and then add someone else i get the message "it's already in !". The think is that listElemetn.text is undefined?!

Comment: Oops my mistake...I forgot something in your code that wasn't needed. Please try the updated version and let me know. Thanks !

Comment: no still not working...have to change everywhere the listElement.text to firstname...is there a way to reference the text of the li element?

Comment: @Linda I apologize, my mistake, I forgot to remove it also from the if statement. Please try the updated version and let me know. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

replace the `listElement.text` with `firstname`.

`listElement.text` will return the `<li>` and so `listElement.text` will be undefined.
u can `console.log` to check it

```
function changeText2() {
var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
var listElement = list.getElementsByTagName("li");

if (addedNames.indexOf(firstname)==-1){
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstname));
    list.appendChild(entry);
    // We add the inserted name in the array for later checks.
    addedNames.push(firstname);
    console.log(addedNames)
}
else alert("is already in !");
```

}